# How to destroy an angularjs app after manually adding to DOM?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I need to add  and remove dynamically a application with angular.bootstrap. I successfully add an application to DOM but in my page must add  the application and remove again and again. I want to remove the application that manually added with angular.bootstrap, What should I do?

```
var mainModule = angular.module('mainApp', []);   
mainModule.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {

$scope.add = function ()
{  
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('myApp'), ['myModule']);  
}

$scope.remove = function ()
{  
 //this here, i want remove 'myModule'  
}
});
```

Comment: I know you asked this 3 and a half years ago, and a lot of things were changed, but did you got a solution for this? :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you load module inside array so yo should treat it as array. So if you have to remove an element from array use splice function. 
So an example should be:

```
array = ['module','module1'];
var index = array.indexOf('module');
array.splice(index,1);
```

Comment: I want add 'myModule' application again and again without page refresh, and if the application before botstrapped to page, try again add it occur a error

Comment: You can try to push 'myModule' inside array of modules, the only thing you have to watch is to make array as a global variable